# Is it possible to make multiple calls using Jsonp with deferred objects?

Tags: ajax, jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to make two or more requests all at once if that's even possible? I'm concerned about speed since after the first request is made I want to display that info onto a web page and then do the same for each additional url.

I've been reading about deferred objects and trying some examples, and so far I've tried to do this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script >
$(document).ready(function($) {
// - 1st link in chain - var url = 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/
catalog/items?parentId=504108e5e4b07a90c5ec62d4&max=60&offset=0&format=jsonp';
// - 2nd link in chain - var url = 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/
catalog/itemLink/504216b6e4b04b508bfd333b?format=jsonp&max=10';
// - 3rd (and last) link in chain - var url = 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/
catalog/item/4f4e4b19e4b07f02db6a7f04?format=jsonp';

// parentId url
function parentId() {

//var url = 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/items?parentId=
504108e5e4b07a90c5ec62d4&max=3&offset=0&format=jsonp';

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/items?parentId=
        504108e5e4b07a90c5ec62d4&max=3&offset=0&format=jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {},
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
}

// itemLink url
function itemLink() {

    //var url = 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink
    /504216b6e4b04b508bfd333b?format=jsonp&max=10';

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink
        /504216b6e4b04b508bfd333b?format=jsonp&max=10',
        jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {},
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
}

// Multiple Ajax Requests 
$.when( parentId(), itemLink()).done(function(parentId_data, itemLink_data) {
    console.log("parentId_data.items[0].title");

});

});
```

But it doesn't seem like the functions are functioning. I was expecting to be able to put some stuff after the .when() method inside the function to tell my program what to do, but I'm not getting anything displayed??

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that in the done handler for $.when, the arguments that are passed to the callback are the array of arguments for each request, not simply the data that you want to use.  You can get around this by using [.pipe](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) as in the example below.

Also, don't specify jsonpCallback unless you have a very good reason, most of the time you want to let jQuery manage that internally for you.

Here's a working example tested on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZzmF/)

```
jQuery(function($) {

    function parentId() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/items?parentId=504108e5e4b07a90c5ec62d4&max=3&offset=0&format=jsonp',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        // We'll use pipe here so that rather than the value being passed to our $.when handler
        // is simply our data rather than an array in the form of [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
        }).pipe(function( data, statusText, jqXHR ) {
            return data;
        });
    }

    function itemLink() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink/504216b6e4b04b508bfd333b?format=jsonp&max=10',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        }).pipe(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
    }

    // Multiple Ajax Requests 
    $.when( parentId(), itemLink()).done(function(parentId_data, itemLink_data) {
        console.log( parentId_data, itemLink_data );
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm still kind of confused by this part "the arguments that are passed to the callback are the array of arguments for each request" ? Also, my original question probably doesn't make sense. What I'm trying to do is take information from the first link and display on a web page. I know if I use the first url with a ajax request and put a for loop inside like this

Comment: -continued from above comment- data.items[i],id to get the id to display. Once I start using the .when() like what you have I can't get anything to display, nor does it give me any errors?? Should I do parent_data.items[i].id??